# Expose properties on TextRange for PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

Using old interop I can access `shape.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID`. I see the preview of office.js for PowerPoint expose TextRange with a limited set of properties. Any plans to expose `LanguageID` or other missing properties?

Or if possible provide generic getters/setters as long as you known the property name of an object.

Reason I ask is that I have an old VSTO which sets the same language on all shapes, very useful in multi-national companies where multiple people edit a deck, leading to spell squigglies all over. And would be nice to use this in non-Windows versions of PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft plans to add more shape properties in the future, but I don't know if TextRange.LanguageID will be included and I can't give you an ETA. I recommend that you make this suggestion at [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).